# Unresolved external symbol after moving to OneApi Fortran with Abaqus

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran, abaqus

I'm facing a problem to compile Fortran routine with Abaqus and the new Intel Fortran compiler (oneApi).

I already follow other help to install OneApi software. I link it with Visual Studio 2017.
And I reach to compile simple Fortran routine.

But when I call an Abaqus function, I have this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol GETVRM referenced in function usdfld
```

This routine was functional before with the ex Intel Fortran compiler.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. We will need as many details about your configuration as possible. How is your Visual Studio configured? Are you able to do your linking on the command line?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Visual Studio is community version 2017 (with defaults parameters). I tried to link it with the Intel OneApi command prompt, but also with command line. I call the vars.bat file to do it.

Comment: What is the content of the bat file? Where does it come from? How did you use it?

Comment: It is a Intel batch file. The path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\env\vars.bat . I call it with intel64 vs2017 options. This batch file is an Intel property file to link Fortran and Visual Studio.

Comment: And how did you do the linking in the command line? Which exact commands did you run? What was the exact output? Please [edit] your question with as many details as possible. Be aware that Intel has a support forum for their products. It is quite active.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help on comments. I found the answer on Intel Forum.

In fact, Abaqus is not updated with new Fortran version. So, Abaqus parameters has top be changed.

The following line must be added on the file win86_64.env :
compile_fortran += ['/names:lowercase',]

I hope this could help somebody.